# Button open a new Blade page in Laravel 5.1

Tags: forms, button, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have only seen how to open a Blade page with link, how do I use a button to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a button like this?

```
<input type="button" 
onClick="parent.location='https://google.com'" 
value="Google" 
formtarget="_blank">
```

Using `Form` facade:

```
{!! Form::button('Google', [
        'onClick' => "parent.location='https://google.com'",
        'formtarget' => 'fromtarget'
    ]) 
!!}
```

And Using `Form` facade with `url()`:

```
{!! Form::button('Delete account', [
        'onClick' => "parent.location='" . url('delete/1') . "'",
        'formtarget' => 'fromtarget'
    ]) 
!!}
```

Comment: Yes, but this wouldn't work. It's plain HTML not in blade format. I'm using Laravel 5.1.

Comment: Blade has nothing to do here, because the code will work even the file is not a blade view. Also, I have tested the code and it works for me. Could you please test again?

Comment: The reason why this is a concern is that I'm passing in the id of the value. i want to delete a user using something like this:

Comment: <input type="button" class="css-deletebutton" onClick="window.location.href='users/show, $users->id';" value="DELETE"> but this is not working. I want to load the show page and then delete the user. If I'm using a link it works well but not with button.

Comment: It is not `window.location.href`, instead use `parent.location`

Comment: I have tried adding an ID but didn't work. This is my snippet: <input type="submit" onClick="location.href ='" .{{ url('users/'.$users->id) }} ."'">

Comment: Why `type="submit"`? are you using a form element? If you are, then just add this attribute to your form: `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with either a `button` or `input` element.

Here's an example with `input`:

```
<input type="submit" onClick="location.href = '{{ url('some/route') }}'">
```

Comment: I have tried adding an ID but didn't work. This is my snippet: <input type="submit" onClick="location.href ='" .{{ url('users/'.$users->id) }} ."'">